# Where are people getting that rotating loading image?

Tags: ajax, image, animation

I keep running across this loading image

http://georgia.ubuntuforums.com/images/misc/lightbox_progress.gif

which seems to have entered into existence in the last 18 months.  All of a sudden it is in every application and is on every web site.  Not wanting to be left out is there somewhere I can get this logo, perhaps with a transparent background?  Also where did it come from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get many different AJAX loading animations in any colour you want here: [ajaxload.info](http://www.ajaxload.info/)

Comment: The http://ajaxload.info seems to be the standard generator for these but it is limited to the smaller images. I would be interested in seeing a generator for larger images (for use in overlays possibly)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the animation came from the Mac OS X loading screen. Here's a similar one with a transparent background:

[alt text http://homepage.mac.com/xraydoc/.Pictures/spinner.gif](http://homepage.mac.com/xraydoc/.Pictures/spinner.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a general extension to the normal clock-face style loading icon.  The Firefox [throbber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber) is the first example of that style that I remember coming across; the only real difference between that and the current trend of straight lines is that the constituent symbols have been stretched to give a crisper look, moving back to more of a many-handed clock emblem.